# Numeric value '{userId}' is not recognized

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL query written in Java that looks like this:

```
public void getTransactionHistoryTest(String userId) {
     String q = "SELECT * FROM \"TEST\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE\" WHERE \"ID\"='{userId}'";
     return  jdbcTemplate.query(query, rs -> {
    }, userId);
    }
```

I have a table in Snowflake where `UserID` is of type `NUMBER`, and I am getting the next error:

> Numeric value '{userId}' is not recognized

To solve this problem, I tried to cast `String` `userId` to `int` like this:

```
int userId= Integer.parseInt(id);
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Is it possible to send `String` value cast it to `int` and still make it work in Snowflake?

Comment: have you tried construct your query like `String q = "SELECT * FROM \"TEST\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE\" WHERE \"ID\"" + userId;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ? character instead of '{userId}'

```
public List<TransactionHistory> getTransactionHistoryTest(String userId) {
 String q = "SELECT * FROM \"TEST\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE\" WHERE \"ID\"=?";
 return jdbcTemplate.query(q, ROW_MAPPER, userId);
}
```

Your issue is caused not by the value of user Id, but by the incorrect escaping of the parameter. In  your case you don't need named parameter - so just **?** will work. Otherwise use named parameter template. See more examples i.e. here https://javabydeveloper.com/spring-jdbctemplate-query-examples/

Another way to try:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM \"TEST\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE\" WHERE \"ID\" = ?";
jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
        new Object[] { userId },
        new int[] { Types.INTEGER },
        ROW_MAPPER);
```

Comment: I did but then I get `Bind variable ? not set.`

Comment: In that case provide  SqlParameterValue instead of user Id, i.e. new SqlParameterValue(Types.INTEGER, userId). Also please share ROW_MAPPER related code

Comment: Sorry I wont be using ROW_MAPPER as my function will return void. Can you give example with SqlParameterValue(Types.INTEGER, userId) I updated my code

Comment: even if I add `new SqlParameterValue(Types.INTEGER, userId)`I am getting same error `Bind variable ? not set`

Comment: you will need row mapper anyways to interpret results

Comment: I suspect you get "Bind variable ? not set" due to passing something incorrect in ROW_MAPPER